# Relating the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ to the modular factorizations of $f$.

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

For the purpose of this question, a partition of a positive integer $n$ is a non-increasing sequence of positive integers whose sum is $n$.

For example, the partitions of $4$ are
$
\,(1,1,1,1),\;\,
(2,1,1),\;\,
(2,2),\;\,
(3,1),\;\,
(4)
$.

If $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n\ge 1$, then for each prime $p$ we can associate a partition $P(f,p)$ of $n$ as the non-increasing sequence of degrees of the monic irreducible polynomals in the complete factorization of $f$ in $F_p[x]$.

For example, for $f=x^5+x^4-4x^3-4x^2+5x+4$, then as shown in the following table
$$
\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|}
\hline
p&\text{factorization of $f$ in $F_p[x]$}&P(f,p)\\
\hline
11&x^5+x^4+7x^3+7x^2+6x+4&(5)\\
\hline
2&x(x^4+x^3+1)&(4,1)\\
\hline
5&(x^3+4x+2)(x^2+x+2)&(3,2)\\
\hline
7&(x+2)(x+6)(x^3+5x+5)&(3,1,1)\\
\hline
3&(x^2+1)^2(x+1)&(2,2,1)\\
\hline
61&(x+29)(x^2+59x+29)(x+20)(x+15)&(2,1,1,1)\\
\hline
563&(x+344)(x+439)(x+40)(x+139)(x+165)&(1,1,1,1,1)\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
*all* partitions of $5$ are realizable as $F(f,p)$ for some prime $p$.

This phenomenon appears to be related to the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Based on a fair amount of testing, I'll pose the following conjecture . . .

**Conjecture:**$\;$If $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with degree $n\ge 1$ is monic and irreducible, the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is equal to $S_n$ if and only if all partitions of $n$ are realizable as $F(f,p)$ for some prime $p$.

**Question:**$\;$Is the conjecture true?

Comment: See corollary 14.8.41 of Dummit and Foote : for any $p$ not dividing the discriminant of $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ contains an element with cycle decompositoin $(n_1, ... n_k)$, where $n_1, ... n_k$ are the degrees of the irreducible factors of $f(x)$ reduced modulo $p$.